# How to count only "Person" box in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the idea of counting all object that was detected, but I can't just count the number of persons that detected.

```
def detected(score, types):

  if (types == 1):

    if(score > 50):

      print('human detected')

      final_score = np.squeeze(scores)    
      for i in range(100):
        if scores is None or final_score[i] > 0.5:
                z.humancount = z.humancount + 1
```

In tensorflow, the "types" for person is equal to 1. After detect everything with tensorflow, I wish to only count the number of person detected, regardless other object detected. 
Please help me if you know the idea to solve it. Thank you so much.

Comment: How about you add a counter.. if types ==1 and score > 50: counter = counter +1

Comment: Nope, not working lol